# Video driver lost after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, 18.04, upgrade, video

I recently upgraded my laptop from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 to 18.04 and now I have a problem with video rendering.  Video rendering of windows is extremely sluggish and sometimes repainting of a window after moving it just doesn't happen at all.  Smaller windows seem to work better than maximized ones.  I assume it's because 18.04 has dropped support for my laptop, which is an HP ProBook 4230s?  Everything was working flawlessly before the upgrade.  I assume it's a driver issue and if I could reinstall the one I had it would fix the problem?

Is there a procedure I can follow to reinstall the previous driver? or what do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

If proprietary, your video drivers and (if you were using it) CUDA should have been removed prior to distribution upgrade. If not using proprietary drivers, your laptop should be using the open source nouveau drivers that normally do not have varying performance between distribution upgrades on the same hardware. Video rendering is dependent on either your CPU or GPU. Your laptop utilizes integrated Nvidia graphics, leading me to believe that the problem is that your videos are being rendered by your CPU.

If you simply need drivers that are not nouveau, type `ubuntu-drivers devices` in your terminal and use `apt` to install the recommended drivers.

On video rendering: You need to install CUDA to enable video encoding/rendering on your GPU. [Here are instructions to install CUDA on Ubuntu](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html).

On video playback: If you are using Firefox, go to about:preferences and make sure hardware acceleration is enabled. If you are using a media player, such as VLC, the option to use hardware acceleration will also be in the options for most media players.

Offtopic, if your organization does do proper in the world, I wish you well. But as you are using this question as a platform to promote your organization, it does not speak well of the morality nor virtue of your organization when unsolicited advertisement is placed on an unrelated website. I suggest you use a more direct way and/or proper channels of communication for exposure.